# I want to create a +score system

Tags: android, crash

So I created a game where u can move your character and u need to pass lines with that character, but I have 1 problem. When the first line reaches bottom of my screen only then the score starts counting. I want to make so that when my character passes the lines gap the score would +1. What should I do?
EDIT: Also the score counts when last line reaches bottom!

```
 if (obstacles.get(obstacles.size()-1).getRectangle().top >= Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT ){
        int xStart = (int) (Math.random()*(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH- playerGap));
         obstacles.add(0, new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart, obstacles.get(0).getRectangle().top - obstacleHeight - obstacleGap, playerGap));
        obstacles.remove(obstacles.size()-1);

        score++;

    }

}

public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    for(Obstacle ob : obstacles)
        ob.draw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(100);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawText("" + score, 50, 100 + paint.descent()- paint.descent(), paint);
```

EDIT:

```
int currY = -5*Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/4, rect;
    while(currY < 0){
        int xStart = (int) (Math.random()*(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH-     playerGap));
        obstacles.add(new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart, currY, playerGap));
        currY += obstacleHeight + obstacleGap;
    }
    if (obstacles.get(obstacles.size() - 1).getRectangle().top >= currY) {
        score++;
    }
```

EDIT2:

```
 private void populateObatacles(){
    int currY = -5*Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/4;
    while(currY < 0){
        int xStart = (int) (Math.random()*(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH- playerGap));
        obstacles.add(new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart, currY, playerGap));
        currY += obstacleHeight + obstacleGap;
    }
}
```

EDIT3:

```
  if (obstacles.get(lastLineScored-1).getRectangle().top >= currY) {
            score++;
            lastLineScored--;
        }

        if (obstacles.get(obstacles.size()-1).getRectangle().top >=  Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT ){
            int xStart = (int) (Math.random()*(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH- playerGap));
            obstacles.add(0, new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart, obstacles.get(0).getRectangle().top - obstacleHeight - obstacleGap, playerGap));
            obstacles.remove(obstacles.size()-1);
            lastLineScored++;
        }
        }
    }

 public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    for(Obstacle ob : obstacles)
        ob.draw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(100);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawText("" + score ,  50, 100 + paint.descent()- paint.descent (), paint);
```

EDIT4:
    Obstacle manager http://pastebin.com/6E77QtHj
    Obstacle http://pastebin.com/p33mPrat

Answer (score 0):

Change your test. Instead of checking whether the top of the line is greater than `SCREEN_HEIGHT`, check whether it is greater than the character's Y coordinate. Also, you need to check against each

```
if (obstacles.get(obstacles.size()-1).getRectangle().top >= /** character Y coordinate */) {
    score++;
}

if (obstacles.get(obstacles.size()-1).getRectangle().top >= Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT ){
    int xStart = (int) (Math.random()*(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH- playerGap));
    obstacles.add(0, new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart, obstacles.get(0).getRectangle().top - obstacleHeight - obstacleGap, playerGap));
    obstacles.remove(obstacles.size()-1);
}
```

EDIT: You need to keep track of which lines are already past the character and only up the score when a new line goes past. You'll need to keep an index of which lines have already been scored. So create a field to keep that index; let's call it `lastScoredLine`. It should be initialized to `obstacles.size()`. You'll have to adjust that field whenever a line falls off the screen.

```
if (obstacles.get(lastLineScored-1).getRectangle().top >= /** character Y coordinate */) {
    score++;
    lastLineScored--;
}

if (obstacles.get(obstacles.size()-1).getRectangle().top >= Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT ){
    int xStart = (int) (Math.random()*(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH- playerGap));
    obstacles.add(0, new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart, obstacles.get(0).getRectangle().top - obstacleHeight - obstacleGap, playerGap));
    obstacles.remove(obstacles.size()-1);
    lastLineScored++;
}
```

Comment: I edited this post. That should be the Y coordinates?

Comment: @nilsllucans - If that's the Y coordinate of the character, then yes. However, my answer is wrong because it only tests the last line. (My answer assumes that when you referred to "lines", that is the same thing as the elements of the `obstacles` array.)

Comment: Now when I go into game it is just black screen.

Comment: @nilsllucans - Sounds like you have an infinite loop somewhere that's blocking your UI thread. Without seeing more of your code, it's impossible to offer solutions.

Comment: Check EDIT2 that is what creates obstacles I think

Comment: @nilsllucans - As long as `obstacleHeight + obstacleGap` is positive, I don't see how that would lock up your system. I gather that there's some sort of game loop running. How is that set up? (P.S. this seems to be evolving into a different discussion. Perhaps you should post a new question to deal with the new problem of a black screen.)

Comment: Ok, I will but I have 1 last question. Should lastLineScored be private int ?

Comment: @nilsllucans - I would think so. Since it's an index it needs to be an integer and there's no reason to make it accessible to code outside where it is used.

Comment: My daily question limit is reached, but I think maybe the problem is with lastLineScored. I added in EDIT3 what I did.

Comment: @nilsllucans - Well, that doesn't have any loops, so I don't see how that can be blocking anything. I don't know anything about the rest of your code (including whatever method the `obstacles` testing code is located), so it's hard to suggest where else for you to look. Perhaps you can put in some logging to check whether the `draw` method is being called and what it's doing internally.

Comment: I uploaded code you can check. If you need more code just say.

Comment: @nilsllucans - I don't see anything there that would explain a blank screen. Where's your animation loop (where `ObstacleManager.update()` is called)?

Comment: @nilsllucans - Well, that still doesn't show the game loop. Where's the loop that is responsible (either directly or indirectly) for calling the `Scene.update()` method?

Comment: One of these must be. I added many because if you need some more here are them. If you need more say, but I think you won't need more. Scene Management : pastebin.com/3QEgA2Ns Scene: pastebin.com/GAG3VXW3 Animation: pastebin.com/Ni8BJHHe Animation Manager: pastebin.com/4ed4uh55 Main Thread : pastebin.com/N2JK4jNE